# Catching multiple exceptions - Python

Tags: api, python-2.7, streaming

I have a program that occasionally throws a badStatusLine exception, after catching it we are now getting another error and I can't seem to catch it so the program doesn't stop.  Here is what I have, any help would be appreciated.

The error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/mattduhon/trading4.py", line 30, in trade
    execution.execute_order(event)
  File "/Users/mattduhon/execution.py", line 33, in execute_order
    params, headers
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1001, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1029, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 892, in putrequest
    raise CannotSendRequest()
CannotSendRequest
```

The file responsible for catching the error:

```
import httplib
import urllib
from httplib import BadStatusLine
from httplib import CannotSendRequest

class Execution(object):
    def __init__(self, domain, access_token, account_id):
        self.domain = domain
        self.access_token = access_token
        self.account_id = account_id
        self.conn = self.obtain_connection()

    def obtain_connection(self):
        return httplib.HTTPSConnection(self.domain)

    def execute_order(self, event):
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + self.access_token}
        params = urllib.urlencode({
            "instrument" : event.instrument,
            "units" : event.units,
            "type" : event.order_type,
            "side" : event.side,
            "stopLoss" : event.stopLoss,
            "takeProfit" : event.takeProfit
        })
        self.conn.request(
            "POST",
            "/v1/accounts/%s/orders" % str(self.account_id),
            params, headers)
        try:
            response = self.conn.getresponse().read()  
        except BadStatusLine as e:
            print(e)
        except CannotSendRequest as a:  ######my attempt at catching the error
            print(a)
        else:          
            print response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the final `else` to:

```
except:
    print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    raise
```

You should get the real uncaught error if it's really coming from the try-catch block.  But are you sure you haven't gotten into a bad state which excepts outside that block?

Comment: No I'm not sure, I'm just going off the errors thrown.  What should I do If the program is excepting outside the block?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if you move the try block up one line so it includes the request? That's not being caught right now, but I don't think it is exception-safe

Comment: I'l give that a try as well..  I think the problem is stemming from someplace else though, like you are saying.  Right befor I get this error the stream from the API I'm accessing outputs '' and thats it, then I get an error..